# Can I put more then 1 of these on a page

Tags: javascript, css

Is there a way to have more then one of these codes on a page. I tried adding 4 and renamed them but still didn't work only the original one still worked. Did i do something wrong or can only 1 work per page. Any help in solving this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks and have a great evening.

```js
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.dropbtn {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.dropbtn a {
  color: black;
  display: block;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-top: 25px;
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-content {
  background: rgba(34, 34, 34, .25);
  border: 1px solid rgba(34, 34, 34, .50);
  display: none;
  height: 100x;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 15px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 525px
}

.show {
  display: table
}
```

```html
<a onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn" style="float:right;">Search Amazon</a>





<div class="dropdown">
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <script type="text/javascript">
      amzn_assoc_ad_type = "responsive_search_widget";
      amzn_assoc_tracking_id = "capebretons0b-20";
      amzn_assoc_marketplace = "amazon";
      amzn_assoc_region = "CA";
      amzn_assoc_placement = "";
      amzn_assoc_search_type = "search_box";
      amzn_assoc_width = "auto";
      amzn_assoc_height = "auto";
      amzn_assoc_default_search_category = "";
      amzn_assoc_theme = "light";
      amzn_assoc_bg_color = "FFFFFF";
    </script>
    <script src="//z-na.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/q?ServiceVersion=20070822&Operation=GetScript&ID=OneJS&WS=1&Marketplace=CA"></script>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: More than one of what? It's not entirely clear what you're looking to do :-)

Comment: You probably only changed the function name. You need to change your function name and add unique IDs for each button so you can linked them to their respective functions. You can use a common function too but that would require a different approach from what you have done above.

Comment: Put another way, you can copy the anchor 4 times and change the text, but they will all call the same function which shows the same amazon div.